# Add cell reference based on end of dynamic column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add a cell reference to another cell. The cell reference is at the end of a dynamic column. The code I have at the moment copies the value and places it in my target cell. However, I need the reference. What do I have to change?

The code I have right now is;

```
Dim PSTtotal As Range
Set PSTtotal = Range("F8").End(xlDown)

Range("M16").Formula = ActiveCell
```

I want M16 to be "=F##" (what ever the last row is represented by ##).

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need this:

```
Range("M16").Formula = "=F" & PSTtotal.row
```

or perhaps just

```
Range("M16").Formula = "=" & PSTtotal.address
```